# Mysql - How to update 2 columns in a table where each row is duplicated in join

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table called A with 
A {
    x int,
    y int,
    z int
}
and i have another table B with
B {
    x int
    code string,
    value string
}.
B-> code can have 2 values :{code1,code2} based on which value also differs.
Now i need to update A with y = B.value if code ='code1' and z = B.value if code='code2'. I am trying to do this in single query .
I tried the usual update:
`update A,B
set A.y=if(B.code='code1',B.value,A.y),
A.z=if(B.code='code2',B.value,A,z)
where A.X=B.x .` 
But it is updating only y. I think it is because there are 2 rows being created for each row in A and updation is getting overwritten i guess. Is my reasoning correct? and is there any way to do this in an update query